# Antiderivative Help 

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to find $f(x)$ if I know that
$$f''(x) = -2+12x-12x^2, \quad \; f(0)=4,\ f'(0)=12 $$

First I found the first derivative
$$ f'(x)= -2x+6x^2-4x^3+C$$

and then I found the function, which is:
$$f(x)=-x^2+2x^3-x^4+Cx+D$$

Now I am lost as to what to do with those values they gave me $ f(0)=4,\ f'(0)=12 $

Where do i proceed from here?

Comment: Plug in 0.  And I assume the first $-2x$ is supposed to be $-2$?

Comment: Nope it should be $-2x$ since im finding the antiderivative right?

Comment: So i should plug in 0 for the second and 0 for the first and get those answers back?

Comment: first, in the $f'$ equation, plug in the point $(0,12)$ and solve for the constant $C$. Then do the same for $D$ in the $f(x)$ equation and you're done!

Answer (score 3):

After finding the value of $f'(x)$ with the unknown constant $C$, use the fact that $f'(0)=12$ to determine the value of $C$. That is, since
$$f'(x) = -2x + 6x^2 - 4x^3 + C\quad\text{and}\quad f'(0)=12$$
that means that
$$12 = f'(0) = -2(0) + 6(0)^2 - 4(0)^3 + C.$$
This should tell you the value of $C$.

*Then* find $f(x)$, which will give you another unknown constant $D$. Use the fact that $f(0)=4$ to figure out the value of $D$.

Comment: So i get the calue C = 12. Then i plug in 12 into C into the f(x) and get D right?

Comment: Give it a spin....